# BitTorrentなどのトレントのスマホアプリにおけるp2p技術について

Tags: ipアドレス, p2p

トレントはどのような仕組みでスマホでの利用を可能にしているのでしょうか？
スマホとスマホの直接的な通信をもってp2p技術でダウンロードすることは難しいと思うのですが。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bittorrent` に限って言うならトラッカーが必ずいるので p2p の相手を直接探す必要はありません。トラッカーからもらった swarm な IP アドレス/ポートに接続すればよいだけの話です。

スマホが移動すれば IP アドレスが変わるでしょうが、その際にも当然トラッカーに通知するだけです（既存のピアとの接続は切れてしまうでしょうが）